# Save checkbox state inside material dialog

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I'm trying to have the checkbox inside of a dialog checked when I close it.  This is a list of 10 checkboxes and when I have more than one, I have a button that opens a dialog and on that dialog, I can't make the checkbox state checked when I close it. On my list, the checkbox state is saved but I can't save the state when they load on the dialog. This is what I have:

**Parent component**

```
 <div *ngIf="toggleState[i]" class="toggle-checkbox">
            <mat-checkbox *ngFor="let item of offering.value | slice:0:10" class="col-4" [value]="item"
                [checked]="offeringState[item]" (change)="onOfferingsChange($event, item)" [class.show]="show">
                {{item | translate}}
            </mat-checkbox>

            <!--[ngClass]="{'clicked': openDialog[i]}"-->
            <button *ngIf="offering.value.length > 11" mat-button (click)="show = !show" type="button"
                class="btn optbutton" (click)="openDialog(i)">
                {{ (show ? 'csa.more' : 'csa.more') | translate}}
            </button>
        </div>
```

```
openDialog(index: number): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalShowmoreComponent, {
      width: '250px',
      height: '400px',
      data: {
        dataKey: this.offerings[index],
      },
    })

    //dialogRef.close('offerings' + this.offeringState)

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed')
      //console.log('offeringState' + this.offeringState[2])
      //this.animal = result;
      /*data: {
        myData: 'MY VAR'
      }*/
      console.log(result)
    })
  }
```

This is my dialog:

```
<mat-dialog-content class="content">
    <mat-checkbox *ngFor="let item of data.dataKey | slice:11:50; let i = index" class="col-4"
        (change)="onChangeCategory($event, item)" [value]="item.name" [class.show]="show">
        {{item | json}}
    </mat-checkbox>
</mat-dialog-content>

<mat-dialog-actions class="actions">
    <button class="mat-raised-button btnModal" (click)="close()">Show Less</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

the result from dialogRef is coming `undefined` and I think that's part of the problem as well.

Comment: Check by using ngModel 
<mat-checkbox  [disableRipple]="true" [(ngModel)]="adminCheckBox['selected']"
                           [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" >Action</mat-checkbox>

Comment: that wont do anything